# Array Integer Logic

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse

I have a game with progress chart and an array. I want to have a chart which the player can see its score in its last 5 games.

here's my code in my array

```
int[] Addition = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };

if (score1 == 0) {
    score1 = Game.score;

} else if (score1 != 0 && score2 == 0) {
score2 = 21;
} else if (score2 != 0 && score3 == 0) {
score3 = Game.score;
} else if (score3 != 0 && score4 == 0) {
score4 = Game.score;
} else if (score4 != 0 && score5 == 0) {
score5 = Game.score;
}
```

What is the problem on my logic? when it runs my first game score seems to be right. but when i play one more its just that the 1st element of the array is changing? where Am I wrong? btw please apologize my english. and I appreciate any suggestions and comments. thanks guys

:::**UPDATE**:::

here's my code now. Can someone check if my initialization is correct:

```
public class ProgressGraph extends Activity {
int[] Addition = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openChart();
}

public void openChart() {

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (Addition[i] == 0) {
        Addition[i] = Game.score;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it looks like you're expecting the 'if' block to hit multiple 'else if' branches, which is not like it works in Java.

Comment: Why are you addressing each element of the array individually? Use a loop and indexes instead.

Comment: sir I just want to make each element of my array to be the score of the player consecutively. Im having a hard time with this. Sir @Egor and sir barq can you please give me some blocks of codes that I can depend on and also to have a new learning?

Comment: Try `static int[] Addition = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` That way it will only get called once.

Comment: that solves the problem ! thank you so much ! god bless programmers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
for(int i = Addition.length-1; i > 0; i--){
    Addition[i] = Addition[i-1];
}
Addition[0] = Game.score;
```

This will mean that the most recent game will always be in position 0. If the user plays more than 5 games the oldest score gets replaced.

It also allows the user to be able to score 0.

Comment: Blast it, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

This part of code seems to be good.
I think your score array is reset when you start the second game.
Did you try to print the scores array before the end of the second game ? Does the first score remain stored ?

Then I suggest you to use a loop like that (not tested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (score[i] == 0) {
        score[i] = Game.score;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir yes it is printed. The first score was replaced by the second score which is not right. And also Id try your codes sir but it seems that its still same result as what I had done on if block statement.

Comment: The condition is strict and clear. So I think that the mistake is elsewhere.

Comment: I would assume that declaring your Addition array in the method as opposed to the class if Maxime's answer is not working

Comment: sir what do you mean by opposed to the class?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to move each old score down the list?

```
for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
    Addition[i] = Addition[i-1];
}

Addition[0] = Game.score;
```

In these code samples we've provided, the array values should be initialized to zero:

```
int[] Addition = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Comment: I have a chart that the player see his scores progress in his last 5 games sir

Comment: Do you want new scores at the bottom (use Maxime's code), or at the top (use code Chris Handy and I posted)? You may have something else going on, but, this type of code should work.

Comment: should it remain? int[] Addition = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };

Comment: No, I was just adding a note that the array values should be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your update.
- When you declare the array. The variable has a capital letter so it may have a conflict with a class. Replace `Addition` by `addition`.

With this code, if you start another activity, scores will be reset. You have to use [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) extended class or [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save scores.